# Upload a Word Document with JSP

Tags: java, jsp

The program I am currently working on allows the user to browse files on the server and then download them.  For the download I wrote a JSP to upload the content to the client.  It is passed the name of the file and then sends back its contents.  The code I have bellow currently works great for text files however when I try to download and then open a word document which is as I understand a binary file I get some text, some weird squares, and an error message from MS Word.  I am not sure why it is incorrectly reading the binary data.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>

<%
    final File APP_ROOT = new File(com.mdi.core.config.ProcessConfiguration.getInstance().getStringValue("APP_ROOT"));
    File f = new File(request.getParameter("path"));

    File parent = f;
    boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid && (parent = parent.getParentFile()) != null)
    {
        valid = parent.equals(APP_ROOT);
    }
    if(!valid)
    {
        response.sendError(403, "You can not download this file!");
        return;
    }

    response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+f.getName());

    response.setContentLength((int)f.length());
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setContentType(java.net.URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(f.getName()));
    InputStream fin = null;
    try
    {
        fin = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buff = new byte[512];
        int read;
        while((read = fin.read(buff)) != -1)
            os.write(buff, 0, read);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(fin != null) fin.close();
    }       
%>
```

Also I get this error in the standard output.

```
java.net.ProtocolException: Exceeded stated content-length of: '40220' bytes
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.checkCL(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:146)
    at jsp_servlet._mdi._html._file_upload.__default_file_upload._jspService(__default_file_upload.java:101)
    at weblogic.servlet.jsp.JspBase.service(JspBase.java:34)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.mdi.core.utils.http.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at com.mdi.core.utils.http.ResponseHeaderFilter.doFilter(ResponseHeaderFilter.java:69)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
<Jun 27, 2014 10:46:07 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101083> <Connection failure.
java.net.ProtocolException: Didn't meet stated Content-Length, wrote: '39942' bytes instead of stated: '40220' bytes.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.ensureContentLength(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:446)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.ensureContentLength(ServletResponseImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.send(ServletResponseImpl.java:1511)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1462)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<Jun 27, 2014 10:46:07 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101104> <Servlet execution in servlet context "ServletContext@1188950474[app:Trade module:TA15 path:/TA15 spec-version:null]" failed, java.net.ProtocolException: Didn't meet stated Content-Length, wrote: '39942' bytes instead of stated: '40220' bytes..
java.net.ProtocolException: Didn't meet stated Content-Length, wrote: '39942' bytes instead of stated: '40220' bytes.
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.ensureContentLength(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:446)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.ensureContentLength(ServletResponseImpl.java:1432)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletResponseImpl.send(ServletResponseImpl.java:1511)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1462)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: Nothing like massive code blocks in a JSP to make your eyes bleed. JSP is for _templating_. Java files are for business logic. Your issue is 100% due to character encoding as I see not one single explicit encoding in the whole block.

Comment: But why would the character encoding matter if I am just trying to upload binary data?

Comment: So how should I go about fixing this?

Comment: What type of character encoding should I use?

Comment: Your fundamental problem is that your are using a JSP. A JSP will write _directly to the HTTP response stream_ and it is designed to serve _HTML_. You can, of course, hack the JSP and try to get your output over the stream before the JSP sends anything but this approach is fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Very important is to remove the JSP own whitespace output:**

```
<%@ page contentType="application/octet" import="java.io.*" %><%
%>
```

No white space, and no newline on the last line.
Tip: use a servlet.

Somehow an `os.flush()` still needs to be done.

After comment from @BoristheSpide: forget flushing. I think the spaces caused some problem, Added content type as binary data.

Comment: +1 for _use a servlet_. **Any** whitespace or other content in the JSP will mangle whatever data is being sent.

Comment: The [flush will happen automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8680265/2071828).

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes, strange, I first even wrote `os.close()`. The problem is wrote: `'39942' bytes instead of stated: '40220' bytes..` - bytes are missing!